# MySQL 2 Tables to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a problem with MySQL. I have 2 tables with the same fields, and I want to select those 2 tables and insert it into another one. That's not the problem but the problem is there are sort of duplicate records in there.

Table1

```
+------+-------+-----------+
| Name | Email | telephone |
+------+-------+-----------+
|Harry |       | 902632354 |
| John | ha@as | 927301837 |
| Alan | ajh@i | 928371048 |
+------+-------+-----------+
```

Table 2

```
+------+-------+-----------+
| Name | Email | telephone |
+------+-------+-----------+
|Harry | a@jka | 902632354 |
| Ron  | hs@as | 123308837 |
| Alan |       | 928371048 |
+------+-------+-----------+
```

Output:

```
Harry
John
Ron
Alan
```

So what I want is a unique telephone field with the name field it's like a distinct but the problem is not every email field is the same so that's the problem, I hope someone can help me. And I am sorry for my English, it's not very good

### EDIT:

I want the 2 tables into another table, same fields but the problem is I have double rows.
I want to delete one of the double rows so the telephone field and name field is unique.

The output has to be:

```
Harry, John, Alan, Ron
```

And not:

```
Harry, John, Alan, Harry, Ron, Alan
```

Comment: Im really confused with the question, can you please re-word the last part of the question, what is it exactly that you want?

Comment: Check the edit part, I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Judging from the example it seems that you want the Name field to be unique? is that correct?

Comment: @mk_89 Pairwise uniqueness of `name` and `phone` fields.

Comment: If each record has an e-mail address, how do you decide which one to keep?

Comment: The name and telephone field are not exactly unique because the telephone number can be the same in another row but not with the same name, and the name can ben in another row but not with the other telephone number. And some email fields are empty so I would like to keep with the most information, MAX() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    select name, MAX(email), phone FROM
    (
       Select name, email, phone FROM table1
       UNION
       Select name, email, phone FROM table2
    ) a
    GROUP BY name, phone
    HAVING email=MAX(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
SELECT name, MAX(email), phone
FROM (
  SELECT t1.`name`, t1.`email`, t1.`phone`
  FROM tbl1 t1
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT t2.`name`, t2.`email`, t2.`phone`
  FROM tbl2 t2
) u
GROUP BY name;
```

Here's a [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/193c2/7).